# Image appear from a linked image?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery so I have no idea where to start.

I want to make an image appear when I click on a thumbnail. Similar to lightbox, but I want it to show up on the actual page. Is there a plugin or specific functions that would make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just place it on the page in a hidden div and use .show() or toggle() to make it visible?

```
$('.thumb').click(function(){
  $('.image').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [popeye](http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/jquery/popeye/demo.html) for an 'inpage lightbox'